# What is the best way to refactor an if else branch

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-construction

I have an if-else branching like

```
if(name.contains(substring)){
    if(name.contains(substring1)){
        return "this";
    }else if(name.contains(substring2)){
        return "that";
    }
    ...
}else if(){
     // if else ladder
}
....//else if ladder continues
else{
    return "them"
}
```

What is the best way to refactor this? That what is the most efficient way to make logic like this?

Comment: Depends upon what type of logic you want o perform in it. What is the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excessive `if/else` or `switch` statements may indicate poor design.

In some situations it could be better to use interfaces (polymorphism), see for example [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html).

Certainly not all `if`s are unnecessary. But it's good to avoid mixing control structures with doing work as much as possible. In the end, code should be easily readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use switch statement instead else if ladder. Since the compiler is capable of optimizing the switch statement, they are generally considered to be more efficient.